# Why am I getting the error SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1

Tags: java, excel, jdbc

I am using the following code for uploading keywords & count to an Excel file. I am having `keyword_id` as a primary key for that one. I am having the two columns in the Excel file. 1.keyword and 2.count

My code is:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    System.out.println("inside ");
    String keyword = rs.getString(1);
    int count = rs.getInt(2);
    System.out.println("insert into SEARCHABLE_KEYWORDS values ('"+
        keyword+"','"+count+"')");
    stmtdb.execute("insert into SEARCHABLE_KEYWORDS (keyword_id,keyword,count) values ('"+ 
        "select Searchable_Keywords_sequence.nextval from dual"+
        "','"+keyword+"','"+count+"')");
    System.out.println(keyword + " " + keyword+" count "+count);
}
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1.
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6998)
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7155)
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecDirect(JdbcOdbc.java:3151)
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.execute(JdbcOdbcStatement.java:378)
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.executeQuery(JdbcOdbcStatement.java:284)
 at keywordsreader.main(keywordsreader.java:42)
```

Answer (score 3):

`count` is a reserved keyword so if you have a column in your `SEARCHABLE_KEYWORDS` table called `count` then you need to put the column name in double quotes (")

Answer (score 2):

Doublecheck the column names in your query. Does the table `SEARCHABLE_KEYWORDS` has the columns `KEYWORD_ID`, `KEYWORD` and `COUNT`? As far as I know this error message often is cause by typos or wrong spelling of your column names.

As mentioned by mikej you should also make sure not to use reserved keywords inside your statements without putting them in quotes. This tip applies to your column with the name `COUNT`.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining in your SQL an insert for two values, but you are selecting three.

`insert into SEARCHABLE_KEYWORDS (`**`keyword_id,keyword,count`**`) values ('"+` 
        **`"select Searchable_Keywords_sequence.nextval from dual"+`**
        **`"','"+keyword+`**
        **`"','"+count+"')")` `**